# dsPic33 page erase size

Tags: memory, flash-memory, dspic

I work on dsPic33EP256MC502 application, i need to write on flash to save configuration. All work except erasing page, i erase too much or too many.

Datasheet say page erase page size is "1024 instructions" (3072 bytes)
Since instruction is 24 bits + phantom byte, instruction is 32 bits aligned
We need two address unit to address an instruction

Example :
    0x000000 : [Phantom] [Instruction1] [Instruction1] [Instruction1]
    0x000002 : [Phantom] [Instruction2] [Instruction2] [Instruction2]
    0x000004 : [Phantom] [Instruction3] [Instruction3] [Instruction3]
    0x000006 : ...

A/ Naively i compute **1024 instructions** page size like :

- 4096 bytes (phantom byte included) *[1024 instructions x 4 bytes]*
- 3072 utile bytes. *[4096 bytes x 0.75]*
- So we need 2048 address unit *[4096 / 2]* to address a pages : **0x800 address per page**

B/ I do an empirical test to verify and i found **0x600 address per page**, this mean 1024 instructions is :

- 0x600 is 1536 address
- 3072 bytes (phantom byte included) *[1536 x 2 bytes]*
- 2304 utile bytes *[3072 bytes x 0.75]*
- I found erase page is **768 instructions** *[3072 / 4]*

I don't understand how the datasheet count instructions with or without the phantom byte, three or four bytes ? How many address per page is available ?

Can someone help me to understand my mistake and/or get a good point of view ?

Answer (score 1):

I confirm now 1024 instructions erase page is :

- 4096 bytes (phantom byte included) [1024 instructions x 4 bytes]
- 3072 utile bytes. [4096 bytes x 0.75]
- We need 2048 (0x800) address unit [4096 / 2] to address a page

Be careful to do you test erase-page aligned because if you erase a page at an address in the page, the whole page is erased, this is why my empirical conclusion was bad.

Page  0 : 0x000000 to 0x0007FE
Page  1 : 0x000800 to 0x000FFE
Page  2 : 0x001000 to 0x0017FE
Page  3 : 0x001800 to 0x001FFE
Page  4 : 0x002000 to 0x0027FE
...
Page 84 : 0x02A000 to 0x02A7FE
Page 85 : 0x02A800 to 0x02AFFE *(Last page contain flash config bytes)*
Page 86 : 0x02B000 *(Inexistent page)*